# How to create SVN branch

Tags: svn

I am working on SVN. I have a repository on SVNServer and I want to create a branch in this repository. I have few doubts:

1. Is a branch creation should be done via SVN Server or SVN Client?
2. I tried creating using `svn copy` command on SVN Server but it is not working. 
   I created a branches folder inside repository and executing this command as:

`svn copy d:\sx000\repository\reposphil D:\sx000\repository\reposphil\branches`

`svn error after executing above command: E200007`

Later I tried

`svn copy d:\sx000\repository\reposphil D:\sx000\repository\branches`

`svn error: E155007`

So none of the options are working. Please suggest how should I create a branch now.

Answer (score 4):

You can create branches both ways:

1. Directly on the repository (you get instant changes)
2. In your working copy (where you'll need to commit changes)

I find it easier to use the repository approach. Otherwise, you'd need to checkout your complete repository.

As a general rule (and this applies to all commands, not just copy) you cannot access the repository file directly: you need to use the repository URL, which can have one of these formats:

- file:...
- svn:...
- http:...

That's why this command:

```
svn copy d:\sx000\repository\reposphil D:\sx000\repository\reposphil\branches
         ^^^                           ^^^
```

... fails.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using tortoise svn you can try this: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-branchtag.html

Comment: I did the same thing as mentioned in the document. But strange part is folder created for branch is empty after creating the branch but DB folder has got a new version. Is this expected behavior?

Comment: No, what should happen is that original version stays the same and content of it should be copied to new folder. Try creating folder "branch" using repo browser and then repeat this action placing the copy in that folder.